# Oledb and visual foxpro

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

How can I set indexes for field while creating table for visual fox pro(.dbf) in c#(using oledb). I want to create multiple indexes for a table and some of the indexes are expression like (field1+field2).

Comment: You do understand that Visual FoxPro is no longer supported by Microsoft, so i cannot and will never, support x64 operating systems.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant! The OP is trying to solve a specific problem with Foxpro, not advocating its use!

Comment: Plus VFP applications run just fine on 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: @RamHound 95% of what is running on your 64-bit Windows is a 32-bit EXE or DLL, so I fail to see what relevance your comment has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=vfpoledb;data source=c:\")) {
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Table1(Column1 v(10), Column2 v(10))";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([USE Table1 IN SELECT(0) EXCLUSIVE])";        
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([INDEX ON Column1 TAG Tag1])";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([INDEX ON Column1 + Column2 TAG Tag2])";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();          
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```